# Handle dependency conflict in .NET Core project.json

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, project.json

I have a .NET Core project (targeting .NET 4.6) where I have to use both EF Core and EF 6. Since I'm also using MySQL, my `project.json` looks something like this:

```
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework": "6.1.3", // For EF 6
        "MySql.Data.Entity": "6.9.9", // For EF 6 and MySQL
        "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql": "1.1.0", // For EF Core
        ...
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "net461": {}
    },
    ...
}
```

The problem is when I try to use the class `MySqlConnection` like this:

```
var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
```

I get the following error:

```
The type 'MySqlConnection' exists in both 
'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' and
'MySqlConnector, Version=0.7.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

Is there a way for me to specify exactly from which library I want to use `MySqlConnection`, or is there any other way to solve this?

These are my constraints:

- I need EF Core since we use `ASP.NET Core Identity` (and other .NET Core libraries using only EF Core)
- I need EF 6 since we found that at the moment there are no EF Core implementations for MySQL that are good enough for all our needs.
- Since we are using MySQL, I need to use `MySql.Data.Entity` for EF 6 and `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` for EF Core. We've tried to use other libraries for EF Core, but they come with a lot of bugs. We found Pomelo to be the most stable.

**EDIT:**
I think the reason is that `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` references `MySqlConnector` which has the namespace/class `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection`, and so does `MySql.Data.Entity`.

Comment: Use the full namespace? `var connection = new MySql.Data.MySqlConnection(connectionString);`

Comment: @DavidG The full namespace is `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection` but that doesn't work since `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` exists in both packages.

Comment: You might be able to get around this by moving the code into it's own project that only references a single version of the class you need.

Comment: @DavidG Thought about that too, but I'm hoping that there is a better solution, since there is quite a lot of code shared between the parts using EF 6 and EF Core (models, etc)

Comment: You can put the models in their own project and share that too. I find that is a good thing to do anyway.

Comment: @DavidG Yeah I know. But I'm actually trying to minimize the number of projects for the solution, so I'm hoping there is another fix.

Comment: I'd be curious why reducing the number of projects is important, it's just another abstraction to separate your concerns.

Comment: @DavidG As solutions grow and the number of projects in the solution increases, VS load time and build times are increasing. I find that keeping projects to a minimum decreases time spent on waiting for my computer to do things :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that in your project.json

```
"frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50",
      "dependencies": {
        // Your .NET Core dependencies
      }
    },

    "net461": {
      "dependencies": {
           // Your .NET 4.6.1 dependencies
      }
    }
  }
```

Then in your code you can do an interface like:

```
#if NET461
// put your EF usings for .NET 4.6.1 here
#else
// put your EFCore usings for .NET Core
#endif

public interface IDatabase
{
    void Initialize();
    DbContext GetContext();
}
```

Then create two objects that inherits from `IDatabase` interface. One for .NET 4.6.1 and the other for .NET Core

**.NET 4.6.1**

```
#if NET461
// put your usings for EF for net461

public class Database461 : IDatabase
{
    private DbContext context;

    public Database461(DbContext context)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        // initialize stuff if you want
    }

    public DbContext GetContext()
    {
        return this.context;
    }
}

#endif
```

**.NET Core***

```
// notice here that i've put a "!" that means "not"
#if !NET461
// put your usings for EF Core

public class DatabaseNetCore : IDatabase
{
    private DbContext context;

    public DatabaseNetCore (DbContext context)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        // initialize stuff if you want
    }

    public DbContext GetContext()
    {
        return this.context;
    }
}

#endif
```

Finally, in your app, you will initialize at startup your `IDatabase` object using one of the two objects above and do whatever you want.

```
// At startup, somewhere in your app...
static IDatabase database;
public InitializeDatabase()
{
#if !NET461
    database = new DatabaseNetCore(...);
#else
    database = new Database461(...);
#endif

    database.Initialize();
}
```

Hope it helps